# Some Sort of Spacing Issue Underneath Navigation in Twitter Bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation

What is causing the spacing of about 20px below the top navigation on other pages such as About, Video, etc?  You can see on the Homepage that this does not occur and is the same code.  http://knitstitchmedia.com/sandbox/sellebrity/index.html

I have searched for a solution, as well as tried some things on my own, yet have come up empty-handed again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `body` `padding-top` values on your homepage differs from what you have on your other pages. For example, you have the following on your homepage:

```
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 45px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
```

But on your About page you have this:

```
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 60px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
```

So, just sync up all your headers and your page should look ok.

Comment: Gooooood, God, how did I ever overlook that, ha!  Thanks for the head's up, Andres!